# python3 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 1233: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-3.6

I'm reading the book-python crash course. I'm using python3.
in chapter 16, there is code like this:

```
import csv

filename = '/Users/pc/Desktop/CS 
Book/Python_crash_course_practice/16.1/sitka_weather_07-2014.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    print(header_row)
```

but it doesn't work, and gave me an error as below. I don't know how to solve it. Is there someone can help me? thanks.

```
%run -i "/Users/pc/Desktop/CS Book/Python_crash_course_practice/16.1/highs_lows.py"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/pc/Desktop/CS Book/Python_crash_course_practice/16.1/highs_lows.py in <module>()
      4 with open(filename) as f:
      5     reader = csv.reader(f)
----> 6     header_row = next(reader)
      7     print(header_row)
      8 
/Users/pc/Library/Enthought/Canopy/edm/envs/User/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py in decode(self, input, final)
     24 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     25     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 26         return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
     27 
     28 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 1233: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are non-ASCII  characters in your file, so you need to specify the file encoding on reading. 
You can also add this in the first line of your python script, to set utf-8 as default encoding

```
#!/usr/bin/env python # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about what exactly the issue is and how your answer is going to solve it.